Using a variable with SFTP ran within a UNIX script
Trying to pull a file off of our db server and bring it to our app server (both AIX).
The file has a timestamp on the end of it to make it unique ex. UA401.dat.
The process is...

A cobol program builds the filename, the executes a shell script that runs a pl/sql piece to build the file on our database server
2 next the cobol program executes a second shell script and passes multiple parameters including the filename to it. this script then moves the filename to a variable and finally uses SFTP to pull the file from the database server to the app server.

Everything works fine except when the SFTP runs it doesn't like the variable in it.
Here is pieces of the code...
FILENM=$4

echo
echo "starting sh4 - friday am - area 2" 
echo $1 "  " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5
echo "now lets try the new varialbles"
echo ${FILENM}
echo ${EMAILADDR}
echo
echo "new code"
echo

sftp  pclawson@lawdbtst1.hs.uab.edu
"lcd /LAWSON/lsfenv1/Interface_Dir/outbound"
cd "/ORACLE/bin/app/oracle/local/INFORT/Interface_Dir/outbound"
"get ${FILENM}"
quit

Here is the output in the log...
starting sh4 - friday am - area 2  
         10    11-DEC-23   12-DEC-23   UAB401124711.dat   kkemp@uabmc.edu  
         now lets try the new varialbles  
         UAB401124711.dat  
         kkemp@uabmc.edu  
                 
         new code  
                 
Connected to lawdbtst1.hs.uab.edu.  
/LAWSON/lsfenv1/Interface_Dir/scripts/klktheory/./klktheory4.sh[44]: lcd /LAWSON/lsfenv1/Interface_Dir/outbound:  not found  

/LAWSON/lsfenv1/Interface_Dir/scripts/klktheory/./klktheory4.sh[45]: /ORACLE/bin/app/oracle/local/INFORT/Interface_Dir/outbound:  not found  

/LAWSON/lsfenv1/Interface_Dir/scripts/klktheory/./klktheory4.sh[46]: get UAB401124711.dat:  not found  

/LAWSON/lsfenv1/Interface_Dir/scripts/klktheory/./klktheory4.sh[47]: quit:  not found  


recommend you change any user/institution identifiable information of generic identifiers. (user@test.edu, /path/to/data/dir, etc) . You probably need a "Here-document" to feed those sftp commands into the sftp std in. Search here for [bash] here document. Good luck.

You need a heredoc
sftp  pclawson@lawdbtst1.hs.uab.edu <<EOF
  lcd /LAWSON/lsfenv1/Interface_Dir/outbound
  cd /ORACLE/bin/app/oracle/local/INFORT/Interface_Dir/outbound
  get ${FILENM}
  quit
EOF

